# Having trouble connecting to datasource in Redhat 7.5

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jboss, driver, datasource

I am in the process of setting up a test machine for redhat sso. I need to connect it to Microsoft SQL server 2016 database. I have installed jdbc driver 7.2. The data source is NON XA. I am having no luck getting it to connect.

I have deployed as core component (jboss7) and also as a deployed package

I am in the process of setting up a test machine for redhat sso. I need to connect it to Microsoft SQL server 2016 database.

jdbc connection string: jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://myserver:1111;DatabaseName=testdb

module.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

Standalone.xml:

jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://myserver:1111;DatabaseName=testdb
                    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
                    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
                    sqlserver
                    
                        user
                        user

expected to connect to the database but I am getting:

the error when I test the connection is: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke an operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://myserver:1111;DatabaseName=testdb` is the wrong connection string if you are using Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver version 7.2. The `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:` was used by the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver and has been replaced by `jdbc:sqlserver:` back in 2005 starting with the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC 2005 JDBC driver.

Refer to [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

So first try `jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1111;DatabaseName=testdb`, if that doesn't work, verify if you aren't accidentally using other no longer valid configuration values. And otherwise, post a new question and make sure to provide all relevant error logs and exception stack traces.

Comment: thanks a lot this was half of the issue. For some reason I had the driver class being called twice. once in the driver I had installed and then calling it again when setting up the datastore. All was good once this and what you stated were removed.

Comment: @Owen I'm not sure what you mean with _"I had the driver class being called twice"_ and why that would be a problem.

Comment: I had first installed the driver using cli. Then when adding the datasource in JBOSS eap it asks to specify driver i had specified the driver class there again. Once i removed them from jboss management console i was able to connect. Im very new at all of this, its a wonder i got this far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the driver class being called twice. once in the driver I had installed and then calling it again when setting up the datastore